# fmBackStyleTransparent não funciona no VBA do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou com um problema no **VBA** do **Excel**, e pelo que pesquisei outros usuários também e estão sem resposta até agora, como neste link.

[propriedade BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent não funciona](http://www.planilhando.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=22347&p=112802)

Ocorre que a propriedade deixou de funcionar nos programas atuais, antigos e ao abrir um novo projeto (começar do zero).

Não faço ideia o que aconteceu.

Se foi por causa da mudança para o Windows 10 eu não sei, pois até então estava funcionando com o Windows 10.

Como fiquei algumas semanas sem usar o VBA, tive essa surpresa desagradável agora.

Alguém sabe o que ocorreu e como resolver?

Grato desde já!

Comment: Olá @Leo, pelo que andei lendo, houve uma atualização agora em outubro que veio com esse bug. Deve ser corrigido em breve, pois já há algumas discussões nos foruns da Microsoft sobre o assunto... mas o fato é que não está funcionando nessa última versão do Office. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985473/office-vba-controls-transparacy-not-working-since-october-2016-office-update

Abs

Comment: @Evert que tal você postar uma resposta com a tradução da resposta original lá do SOen?

Comment: Olá @LuizVieira, postei a resposta, colocando as fontes. ok? Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Microsoft liberou uma atualização (Outubro/2016), para o Office, com um erro que influencia o comportamento do VBA. O que está ocasionando este erro, como podemos constatar no fórum da Microsoft (em inglês):

[Office VBA controls transparacy not working since October 2016 office update](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9796fd67-e65c-4086-a2db-b990a17077b8/office-vba-controls-transparacy-not-working-since-october-2016-office-update?forum=Office2016ITPro)

Link pesquisado: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985473/office-vba-controls-transparacy-not-working-since-october-2016-office-update)

Espero que eles resolvam isso em breve!

Comment: Valeu Evert!!!!