# Label com fundo transparente

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, label

Estou fazendo um programa todo em VBA, no Excel (office 2016), e do nada alguns componentes deixarem de funcionar corretamente. 
A principal, e essencial, mudança foi que nenhum campo fica com o BackStyle transparente (antes funcionava). 
Não fiz atualizações, pc não reiniciou, tentei reparar o office tanto offline quanto online (pelo programas e recursos - appwiz.cpl).
Tentei desinstalar o office por completo, ainda usando a ferramenta 'OfficeRemovePro.diagcab' após removê-lo do meu pc.
Reinstalei o office, mas o problema não resolve.

Alguem saberia ajudar?

Segue abaixo a imagem de um form aleatório que criei, tentei add a label, mudei o BackStyle para transparente, porém não altera. Altera se mudar a cor:

[image: BackStyle não funciona para transparente]

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9796fd67-e65c-4086-a2db-b990a17077b8/office-vba-controls-transparacy-not-working-since-october-2016-office-update?forum=Office2016ITPro

Comment: Segue ai:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161880/fmbackstyletransparent-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-vba-do-excel/161949?noredirect=1#comment333229_161949

Comment: Mt obrigado pela ajuda, @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: Mt obrigado pela ajuda, @Evert